# how to display 1 million data from a table on UI

Tags: java, javascript, oracle, algorithm, data-structures

I have a question which might be a very common issue when data increases
If I am having a table containing 1 million rows
and I want to display it on my browser.

What is the most efficient approach / technique to approach this problem

I assume there should be a concept of pagination or load data as and when the user scrolls down to see more data, but how to hold 1 million data in memory until then, unless I query the table like id>x and id<(x+500) to fetch data in batches of 500..

Kindly share an efficient approach

Thanks

Comment: Use pagination alongwith Ajax

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Comment: Use pagination when user click on the page number set of records has to be retrieved instead of fetching 500 records at the initial stage[Loding the page]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really don't want a resultset with 1000000 rows. Even if you paginated it, no-one's going sit down and read them all. Just put a limit on (say 1000), put a message on the page saying the results are truncated to 1000 rows, and offer filtering.

Comment: That and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You should make query for loading only data you want to display. Or better solution is create query which return data for `"Page before" : "Actual page" : "Next page"` so If you list your data slowly it would be already cached. If you list fast you ll have to wait for your data.

Answer (score 0):

I propose loading 2 * 500 rows at the beginning. The first 500 will be displayed and then you delete it from your program memory, and the other 500 remains cached as to speed up the displaying process when the user scrolls down to the next page. When the user does scroll down to the next page, you display the 500 rows, delete them from your program memory (aka release/delete the array), and requests the next 500 from database in attempt to caching them for display when the user scrolls down further, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pagination or sliders along with ajax. Say, each page can hold 50 records. So based on the onclick event of next page or prev page you will get 50 rows from ajax response and then display it. So at a time you'll fetch only 50 rows.

Answer (score -1):

I 'm using pagination to display my resultset on application because sometimes the data is in millions and sending all data to UI makes DOM heavy resulting in slowness and app unresponsiveness.
For read view I'm good, but in edit view if a user is adding multiple records (thousands or millions) at once (which are essentially pulled from another datasource), how shall I handle that data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refrain from using answers to ask questions.  If you can't find an answer to your question already on StackOverflow, then you will need to create your own.